# Why is this not sorting the list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort the list in ascending order. Please help.

```
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
n = len(A)
def sort (A, n):
    for i in range (1, n):
        for j in range (1, n-1):
            if A[j]>A[j+1]:
                t = A[j]
                A[j] = A[j+1]
                A[j+1] = t
print (*A)
```

Comment: First of all you are not calling sort function. You need to call sort function.

Comment: Why to code when you're having built-in functionality -->> A.sort()

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya he is learning programming i guess. So he is trying to code the sort function. If he use directly inbuilt function then he will not learn basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the sort function which you have defined so I've removed it, if you want to keep it then you have to call it before you print the sorted list. Try the code below:

```
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
n = len(A)
for i in range (n):
    for j in range (i+1, n):
        if A[i] > A[j]:
            t = A[i]
            A[i] = A[j]
            A[j] = t
print (*A)
```

**Result:**

```
2 4 6 7 8 9
```

**ANALYSIS**

First For Loop – First Iteration: for 0 in range(0, 6)
The condition is True. So, it enters into second for loop

Nested For Loop – First Iteration: for 1 in range(0 + 1, 6)
Condition is True. So, it enters into the If Statement

if(A[0] > A[1]) = if(7 > 8) – It means the condition is False. So, it exits from If block, and j value incremented by 1.

Nested For Loop – Second Iteration: for 2 in range(1, 6) – Condition is True

```
if(7 > 6) – Condition is True
    temp = 7
    A[i] = 6
    A[j] = 7
```

Now the List = 6 8 7 4 2 9. Next, j increment by 1.

Do the same for the remaining Iterations in Nested and main for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
n = len(A)
def sort (A, n):
    for i in range (0, n):
        for j in range (0, n-1):
            if A[j]>A[j+1]:
                t = A[j]
                A[j] = A[j+1]
                A[j+1] = t

sort(A,n)
print (*A)
```

Comment: add a bit of explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the sort function to execute it.
See below code:

```
def sort (A, n):
    for i in range (0, n):
        for j in range (0, n-1):
            if A[j]>A[j+1]:
                t = A[j]
                A[j] = A[j+1]
                A[j+1] = t
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
n = len(A)
sort(A,n)
print (*A)
```

There is one more change you are running loop from 1 but it should run from 0 for both loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using sort function.

```
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
print(A)
A.sort()
print(A)
```

Result:

```
[7, 8, 6, 4, 2, 9]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [7,8,6,4,2,9]
n = len(A)
def sort (A, n):
    for i in range (0, n):
        for j in range (0, n-1):
            if A[j]>A[j+1]:
                t = A[j]
                A[j] = A[j+1]
                A[j+1] = t
sort(A, n)
print(*A)
```

Use '0' as start rather than 1 and call the sort function. You will get the output as below.

```
2 4 6 7 8 9
```